# Keeping a variable value on two different pages using jsf managed beans

Tags: jsf-2.2, managed-bean

My site has a page with a datatable. This datatable has a button called 'Edit', where the user can click to edit the data of a single row. When the use clicks on it, he gets redirected to another page, where the data of the selected item will be displayed for him to edit.

The way I make it right now is with a SessionScoped bean, where I can keep the value for the selectedItem variable. However, it feels gross to use SessionScoped here.

Simplified Code:

```
<h:form>
    <p:dataTable id="dataTable" var="item" value="#{exampleController.itens}">
         <p:column headerText="Name">
             <h:outputText value="#{item.name}" />
         </p:column>
         <p:column>  
             <p:commandLink title="Edit" action="/pages/anotherPage?faces-redirect=true">
                  <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{item}" target="#exampleController.selectedItem}" />
             </p:commandLink>
         </p:column>  
     </p:dataTable> 
</h:form>
```

What is a better way of doing this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try view params, that way you win two things:

- Your url becomes friendly, (somethinh like http://localhost/view?param=value)
- You can remove your ugly session bean

To do this you need in your action:

```
<p:commandLink title="Edit" action="/pages/anotherPage?faces-redirect=true">
    <f:param name="foo" value="#{item}"/>
</p:commandLink>
```

And in your edit view:

```
<f:metadata>
  <f:viewParam name="foo" value="#{viewBean.item}"/>
</f:metadata>
```

More info with the great Balus [Balus - Communication in JSF](http://balusc.omnifaces.org/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html#ProcessingGETRequestParameters)

Comment: I've bookmarked it and forgot it. Thanks for the answer!